# Access static field value in protocol extension

Tags: swift, protocols

If I have a protocol like this:

```
protocol X {
    static var typeName: String
}
```

Is there a way for instance methods in protocol extensions to access the value of that field?

```
extension X {
    func getTypeName() -> String {
        // return the static typeName property of this instance's type.
        // I'd expect it to be something like self.Type.typeName, but that's not a thing apparentl.
    }
}
```

Obviously, a simple getter like this is pretty useless, but it's a minimal example of the issue I'm having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Self`:

```
extension X {
    func getTypeName() -> String {
        Self.typeName
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew about `self`, but not its capitalised variant